# Subresource Integrity and Nonce Values

Tags: html, security

Currently, for our web application, we are generating `nonce` values to attach to `script` tags. I have recently found out about [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) and considering that we're using a CDN (as most examples reference), I was curious if this was something my web app should use.

Is there ever a case for both `nonce` and `integrity` attributes to be used? Is one better than the other? Or, do they support multiple use cases entirely?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

They support different use cases and you can use both.

Nonce instructs the browser to execute only `<script>` elements which have the same nonce value set in the CSP header.

> **nonce-***
> **A cryptographic nonce (only used once) to whitelist scripts**. The server must generate a unique nonce value each time it transmits a
> policy. It is critical to provide a nonce that cannot be guessed as
> bypassing a resource's policy is otherwise trivial. This is used in
> conjunction with the script tag nonce attribute. e.g.
> nonce-DhcnhD3khTMePgXwdayK9BsMqXjhguVV

So let's say your application set a `Content-Security-Policy` header like `script-src'nonce-r4nd0m';`  then the script at `good.com/good.js` will be executed because the nonce value is the same.

```
<script nonce="r4nd0m" src="//good.com/good.js">
```

What happens if an attacker compromises `good.com` and add a malicious script to `good.js`? That your web application still allows the execution of that script because *the check is made on the nonce value not on the script content*. So you need also to be sure that the content of `good.js` remains the same.

Here `integrity` attribute is involved. It implements Subresource Integrity and tells to the browser to run resources only if the computed hash matches with the one stored in the `integrity` attribute.

> Subresource Integrity (SRI) is a security feature that **enables
> browsers to verify that resources they fetch (for example, from a CDN)
> are delivered without unexpected manipulation**. It works by allowing
> you to provide a cryptographic hash that a fetched resource must
> match.

So let's suppose the first time you included the script in the web app, the content of the script was safe and the `integrity` value was `X`. Then you added `integrity="sha384-X"` to the script element as follows.

```
 <script src="//good.com/good.js"
        integrity="sha384-X">
```

The attacker modifies `good.js` so the resulting hash of the modified script becomes `Y`. The browser doesn't run the script because the computed hash (`Y`) and the required hash (`X`) don't match.

I think you can combine both like this.

```
<script nonce="r4nd0m" integrity="sha384-X" src="//good.com/good.js">
```